# Service fabric .net core 3 stateless service routing and inter-service communication

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

VS2019 allows us to create stateless services on `.net core 3`. I was not able to find any sample codes on this. How can we enable inter-service communication (.net core 3 gateway communicating with stateless service)?
As far as I know, the reverse proxy or remoting is not implemented yet. What's the best approach for communication and load balance?

Comment: "As far as I know, the reverse proxy or remoting is not implemented yet" - Where is this stated?  I have created stateless netcore3.1 services with service remoting that works as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation in `.net core 3` shouldn't be any different than what you were using previously.

If you're using specific ports, you can just call `http://localhost:<portNumber>`.

If you want to dynamically resolve the service (which would imply that your port is system-assigned and not dev-assigned), an interesting read is here:

https://dzimchuk.net/implementing-a-rest-client-for-internal-communication-in-service-fabric/

You could construct the service fabric reverse proxy uri yourself too, if you know which service you want to call.